# How would I make div stick to top of screen using this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below is test code I'm using. The blue bar is supposed to stick to the top of the screen when it reaches the top.

This works on my browser, but the reason I'm here is because when it sticks to the top, it all of a sudden becomes smaller. As you see the blue bar starts with a full width across the container, but on my computer/browser, after it sticks to the top, the div shrinks to just the size of the text.

To make matters worse, I cannot reproduce the problem on [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPWAC/), because in jfiddle it doesn't work at all! (The images are just there to create a scroll).

Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPWAC/)

Here is the jquery:

```
var titlePosition = $('.title').offset().top;


    $(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollBar = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollBar > titlePosition) {
        $('.title').css("top", "0px");
        $('.title').css("position", "fixed");

    } else {
        $('.title').css("position", "relative");
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback.

Even though it helped improve, in the end the div was still resizing. Fixing the width to specific values was not responsive enough.

I finally stumbled upon a solution, based on all the advice:

http://jsfiddle.net/yPWAC/8/

```
var titleWidth = $('.title').width()

/*then after the div is fixed I change the width */

$('.title').css("width",titleWidth);
```

I made jquery hold the original width of the div, then change the width of the sticky div to whatever that value is.

For some reason, even if I defined the original width in CSS, the new sticky width would still come out a different size in the browser. So this method gives it the same width as the original (whatever it may be)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/yPWAC/1/)**

**CSS**:

```
.title {
    font-size:200%;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. It stops the div from shrinking, but now it expands the div by too much!

If you look at the fiddle ..scroll all the way right before scrolling down. Once you scroll down, you see the div expands to the end of the page. I want it the same length as the first image, or rather the main div. But if I resize the main div, the title div still expands out side of it.

Comment: Yes! What did you change? Margin/Padding?

Comment: I changed the width 86% for image and title div

Answer (score 0):

Update your code:

```
if (scrollBar > titlePosition) {
    $('.title').css("top", scrollBar+"px");
    $('.title').css("position", "fixed");

} else {
    $('.title').css("position", "static"); //otherwise it will still get that top value and cause unwanted position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css:

```
.title {
    ...
    width: 100%;   /*This does the trick*/
}
```

Here you have it working: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/yPWAC/3/

Cheers

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, as above. It stops the div from shrinking, but now it expands the div by too much!

If you look at your fiddle  and scroll all the way right before scrolling down. Once you scroll down, you see the div expands to the end of the page. I want it the same length as the first image, or rather the main div. But if I resize the main div, the title div still expands out side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Set `left` to `0` as well. Additionally, [some optimizations](http://jsfiddle.net/yPWAC/4/).

I prefer appending/removing classes to put all your CSS in your stylesheet. Saves you from problems later on when the code gets huge (who would be looking for CSS in JS files anyway?).

Also, cache objects. Everytime you fire `scroll`, your code fetches every single `.title` in the DOM and generates a jQuery object. Not very optimal. Instead, get all `.title` and just do the modifications on each scroll.

CSS:

```
.title.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

JS:

```
var titlePosition = $('.title').offset().top;
var win = $(window);
var title = $('.title');

win.scroll(function () {
    var scrollBar = win.scrollTop();
    if (scrollBar > titlePosition) title.addClass('fixed');
    else title.removeClass('fixed');
});
```

As for your non-working fiddle, you forgot to include jQuery. That should be found on the top left.

Comment: Okay this was very helpful. I did neglect to add the Jquery options!

However, while this (and other tips from other answers) seems to prevent the div from shrinking, it's now making the dive expand. If you look at the fiddle (your optimization fiddle for example)..scroll all the way right before scrolling down. Once you scroll down, you see the div expands...

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `z-index:999` or, using jQuery - `$('.title').css("z-index", "999");`

Rest looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
var titlePosition = $('.title').offset().top;
```

.top is not a function. offset() returns an object containing the properties  `top` and `left`

Replace with:

```
var titlePosition = $('.title').offset();
```

You can now access the properties like so:

`titlePosition.top` or `titlePosition.left`

reference: .offset() http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Thanks for this tip.
However, the problem seems to remain